# Xamarin.Forms iOS Xamarin.Build.Download Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Since I updated some of my NugetPackages my iOS project is not building because of the mentioned error.

```
\.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.10.0\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(52,3): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I guess its since I updated the Xamarin,Build.Download from 0.8.0 to 0.10.0 but I need the new version because of dependencys of other projects.

Any solutions or work arounds?

Comment: have you try to clear ```obj``` and ```bin``` folders and restores packages and build again.

Comment: Yes, like thousand times

Comment: Aer you building on a PC? There is currently a nasty bug which gives an NRE when building

Comment: Yes, I build on PC with a remote MacInCloud server. Is there any work around?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I'm building again after installing Visual Studio 2019 16.7 Preview 1 (you can install it in parallel to your main VS installation and just use it for builds). Intermittently the builds fail (with a different error) and the only way I know of to get rid of it is to uninstall and then reinstall VS. I guess reinstalling Visual Studio once every few days is part of my "new normal" workflow now!

Comment: I swear that clearing obj and bin folders solves 95% of all Xamarin build errors - they should just put it on a background task in VS and run it every minute.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me in VS 2019 and it was caused by the fact I was trying to build with a provisioning profile which used a new style "Platform All" Apple Certificate. I had edited the csproj directly to embed the provisioning profile name. This was the cause of the build error for me.

Solution was to use the old style "Platform iOS" Apple Certificate and an associated provisioning profile, which is picked up by the project properties.