# having error on xamarin.forms ios when using xamarin.build.download 0.10.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using xamarin forms for my app development. When i run my code for ios from my pc through pair to Mac machine, i am having the following error:

`packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.10.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(52,3): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, cleaning obj and bin folders, as it can solve many builds problems of Xamarin.

Second, from the error message, [it looks like the package you referenced causes the problem](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/182634/error-xamarin-build-download-0-10-0-failing). keeps the packages up to date and avoids using the pre-release version.

Third, the Apple Certificate seems can cause it too, because some people had met the same problem. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264254/xamarin-forms-ios-xamarin-build-download-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance) page for more details.